# Declaration of member which can be either a method with parameters, or a property

Tags: typescript

**How can I model a member which can be both a property (without parameters) or a method (with parameters)?**

The WSH [Enivronment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd(v=vs.84).aspx) property can be called from Javascript without a parameter:

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
var env = shell.Environment;
```

Or, as a property with a parameter, which from Javascript looks like a method call:

```
var filteredEnv = shell.Environment('System');
```

Both cases return an instance of the [WshEnvironment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7w15a0(v=vs.84).aspx), a collection of environment variables.

However, an error is raised when calling as a method without any parameters:

```
var env2 = shell.Environment();
```

I can model it as a property, or as a method with parameters, but not both together:

```
declare interface WshShell {
    // ...

    // Error: Duplicate identifier
    Environment: WshEnvironment;
    Environment(Type: 'System' | 'User' | 'Process' | 'Volatile'): WshEnvironment;

    // ...
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20interface%20WshEnvironment%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20WshShell%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Environment%3A%20WshEnvironment%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Environment(Type%3A%20'System'%20%7C%20'User'%20%7C%20'Proces'%20%7C%20'Volatile')%3A%20WshEnvironment%3B%0D%0A%7D)

---

I could type as `WshEnvironment & {(Type: 'System' | 'User' | 'Process' | 'Volatile'): WshEnvironment}`; and then the following would compile:

```
let x: WshShell;
console.log(x.Environment.Count);
console.log(x.Environment('Process').Count);
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20interface%20WshEnvironment%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Count%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20interface%20WshShell%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Environment%3A%20WshEnvironment%20%26%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Type%3A%20'System'%20%7C%20'User'%20%7C%20'Process'%20%7C%20'Volatile')%3A%20WshEnvironment%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20x%3A%20WshShell%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(x.Environment.Count)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(x.Environment('Process').Count)%3B%0D%0A)

but Typescript would deduce a call signature on the object returned from `x.Environment` to filter the values, while the call signature actually returns a single value with the argument as its variable name:

```
let env = x.Environment;
// Typescript will type filteredEnv as WshEnvironment
// At runtime, filteredEnv will contain an empty string (unless there is an environment variable named 'Process')
let filteredEnv = env('Process');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare an interface that has a call signature that extends `WshEnvironment`

```
// Added for testing 
declare interface WshEnvironment{
    (name: 'OS'): string
}

declare interface WshEnvironmentWithInvoke extends WshEnvironment {
    (Type: 'System' | 'User' | 'Proces' | 'Volatile'): WshEnvironment;
}
declare interface WshShell {

    Environment: WshEnvironmentWithInvoke;

}

let shell: WshShell;
shell.Environment("System")("OS");
shell.Environment("OS");
```

**Edit**

The above solution does allow calls like this to be made:

```
let env = x.Environment;
let filteredEnv = env('System');
```

There is no way unfortunately to type this correctly in Typescript, basically to have a property which looses some attributes when it gets assigned out of the object). I would go for optimizing the common scenario, which here seems to be the version in which you do specify the parameter, mostly because of this line in the documentation :

> If strType is not supplied, the Environment property returns different environment variable types depending on the operating system.

I would with creating a helper function to give some context for the cast, instead of doing it inline:

```
declare interface WshEnvironment{
    (name: 'OS'): string
}
declare interface WshShell {
    Environment (Type?: 'System' | 'User' | 'Proces' | 'Volatile'): WshEnvironment

}

function defaultEnvironment(shell: WshShell) :WshEnvironment {
    return shell.Environment as any;
}
var shell: WshShell = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');

var s = defaultEnvironment(shell);
WScript.Echo(s("OS"));
WScript.Echo(shell.Environment('System')("OS"));
```

Comment: @ZevSpitz, you are right, I will check when I get back from lunch, but I don't think there is a solution to disallow your example.

Comment: (previously deleted comment) The call signature is only valid when used with the member call; see my updated answer.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I checked, the workaround I added is the closest version I can come up with. I don't think there is a way to achieve the result you want. If you want I can delete the answer to encourage others to have a look, but I seriously doubt this can be done.