# Typing as "non-callable"

Tags: typescript

I've [already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48618529/111794) about modelling members which are either a property, or a callable method with arguments. Currently, I am using an intersection type for this:

```
class PageSetup {
    ...
    PrintQuality: SafeArray<number> & ((Index: 1 | 2) => number);
    ...
}
```

This works as long as the type of the property is known. However, the [**Value**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value-property-excel) property on the Excel [**Range** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) in its property form (i.e. without parameters) can return any arbitrary value. The only limitation I can be reasonably certain of, is that the returned value is not callable.

Typing as `Value: any & ((RangeValueDataType: xlRangeValueDataType) => any)` is pointless, because the intersection of `any` and anything else reduces to `any`.

**How can I model this property as `NonCallable & ((RangeValueDataType: xlRangeValueDataType) => any)`?**

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49262929/111794) using the built-in `Exclude` type.